# why don't these stylus hashes behave the same?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stylus

In my Javascript:

```js
// styl is the stylus compiler instance
styl.define('passedHash', new stylus.nodes.Object({
  top: 0,
  right: 2,
  bottom: 5,
  left: 20
}));
```

In my .styl file:

```css
localHash = {
  top: 0
  right: 2
  bottom: 5
  left: 20
}
.fooBar
  nodeType typeof(localHash)
  padding unit(localHash['top'], 'px')
  nodeType typeof(passedHash)
  padding: unit(passedHash['top'], 'px')
```

The compiled output becomes:

```css
.fooBar {
  nodeType: 'object';
  padding: 0px;
  nodeType: 'object';
}
```

If I uncomment that last line in the stylus, I expect the padding rule to be written out exactly the same for `passedHash` as it is for `localHash`. But instead, stylus crashes:

```
TypeError: expected "unit" to be a unit, but got null:null
```

Why? The compiler knows they're both objects... they appear to be the same exact object to me....

Comment: I see a non-consistent `:` in the line `padding: unit(...)`. Not sure if that's just a typo though.

Comment: Aha, that. I tried it with and without that colon because I'd found another thread somewhere suggesting that Stylus had trouble accessing object properties without it being there. Made no difference with or without in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the source of the `Object` node (https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/master/lib/nodes/object.js) you cannot pass a JS object to its constructor. So your `passedHash` is empty and you get that error. However, you can coerce a real JS object to Stylus object using this code:

```
styl.define('passedHash', {
  top: 0,
  right: 2,
  bottom: 5,
  left: 20
}, true); // <-- true for raw coercion
```

Or more verbose version:

```
styl.define('passedHash', stylus.utils.coerceObject({
  top: 0,
  right: 2,
  bottom: 5,
  left: 20
}, true));
```

Comment: Answer makes good sense, but unfortunately neither version worked for me. Same error. Just updated from 0.49 to 0.50 to make sure I was current as well.

Comment: Also noticed that if I comment out the line that triggers the error, the typeof check on the previous line prints `nodeType: 'ident'` instead of `nodeType: 'object'` when using either of the suggestions in this answer.

Comment: Aaaaaand now I see that you're essentially the maintainer of Stylus now, Panya. Thanks for chiming in! So, nothing wrong with the way I'm attempting to use the object in my stylus file?

Comment: Well, I'm really have no idea why it's not working for you. I'm trying your `my.styl` file (without any changes) and this JS code https://gist.github.com/Panya/d7aeb7ab2b9d73033399, all works great.

Comment: Aha, got it, I had not updated Stylus correctly (long story, unusual project setup). It has actually been back on 0.42.x, and it started working when I brought it up to 0.50.x — but I see that hashes landed in 0.39.0, so, did the coerceObject util come sometime between 0.42 and 0.50?

Comment: > so, did the coerceObject util come sometime between 0.42 and 0.50?

yep coerceObject with raw JS object to Stylus hash coercion was added in 0.43.0